# How to disable all password requirements in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, security, authentication

When I try to create a new database using DBCA it stops me because my password isn't complex enough. I am working with Oracle in a VirtualBox VM on my own laptop, so I don't need the password complexity restrictions Oracle imposes out of the box. Personally I don't care if my passwords in this environment are "password" or even a space. Unfortunately I can't seem to find a straightforward answer on how to simply disable password checks. What command do I need to run / switch do I need to flip to turn it off?

I'm on a Windows laptop with Windows 2012 in the VM if that is relevant. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: well you can use 'password' as your password it just shows warning denoting that your are using weak password you can simply ignore it.

Comment: You can try "ALTER PROFILE default LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION NULL;" but there should not be a password verify function setup by default.

Comment: Interesting. When I was using the DBCA tool last night I used 'password' and it prevented me from moving forward because the password did not meet requirements. This was on an almost new install of Oracle. I was using the DBCA because that is the tool used in the 2 day dba tutorial. It is possible that I made a mistake using it so I'll check again when I get home. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DBCA, It will mark the password weakness as an error, push through with the "NEXT" button.

You will be warned again in a pop up box that you are making a serious mistake and are you sure that you want to continue.

Answer "Yes".

It should move on from there.

It's the same pretty much everywhere.

DBCA:
[image]

Grid Infrastructure:
[image]

Comment: You were right. It turns out I was tired at the time and didn't catch the popup error dialog actually reported *two different errors* -- one was the password warning and immediately below it in the same dialog was an error stating I had not specified a file location, since when I selected ASM it automatically cleared those fields. So the *actual error* was regarding the files, not the password. My mistake. Though in partial defense Oracle made that somewhat non-obvious... It even "helpfully" highlights the first error, which isn't even an error in this case. :(